# Use Syntax Highlighter on AJAX loaded content

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting

How can I use Alex Gorbatchev`s Syntax Highlighter on content loaded after 'window' emits 'load' event? I am trying this way:

```
    $.ajax({
        url:    file,
        success: function(data) {
            $('.fileName').text(file);
            $('#fileSource > pre').text(data);
            SyntaxHighlighter.all();
        }
    });
```

... but it is not working. I need to mention that the ajax call can occure at any time after the page loads.

Regards

Comment: `.all()` seems to bind to the window load, maybe call the `SyntaxHighlighter.Highlight` method and pass it the `<pre>` you're looking to highlight? (this is a best-guess)

Answer (score 41):

-`SyntaxHighlighter.all()` binds window load. So if you want to highlight element when the page loads, then use this method.

-`SyntaxHighlighter.highlight()` highlights elements whenever you will call this method. So it's better you use this.

-`SyntaxHighlighter.highlight()` takes two parameter, both are optional.

**1. Parameter *globalParams*:**

@param {Object} globalParams, Optional parameters which override element's parameters. Only used if element is specified.

**2. Parameter *element*:**

@param {Object} element, Optional element to highlight. If none is provided, all elements in the current document are highlighted.

-For more info about this, go to *syntaxhighlighter_3.0.83/src/shCore.js*

Comment: this post helped me to solve problem with ajax content, thanks a lot

Comment: Good for you, and me since I'll use it to, But could you be a dear and mark the answer as correct? Thank you

Answer (score 5):

I`ve found the answer to my question in one of his examples:

```
    $.ajax({
        url:    file,
        success: function(code) {
            $('.fileName').text(file);
            var brush = new SyntaxHighlighter.brushes.JScript(),
                html;
            brush.init({ toolbar: false });
            html = brush.getHtml(code);
            document.getElementById('source').innerHTML = html; 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

just add this section

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.code').each(function () {
            SyntaxHighlighter.all();
        });
    });
```