# Javascript in HTML not working when Panel is used within a Wicket ModalWindow

Tags: javascript, wicket, wicket-1.5

I have several panels that I'm displaying in a ModalWindow. In the html files of those panels I have script-tags in the body, e.g. for SyntaxHighlighter or a JW Player. Those tags work if I embed the panel into its own page. However, they are NOT working when the panel is embedded into a ModalWindow.

Example for a panel (html-file) that displays text which is supposed to be processed by SyntaxHighlighter (this is in the body-tag):

```
<wicket:panel>
  <pre wicket:id="content"></pre>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    SyntaxHighlighter.all();
  </script>
 </wicket:panel>
```

I already tried many different things, e.g.

```
super.show(target);
target.appendJavaScript("SyntaxHighlighter.all();")
```

in the overridden "show()"-method of ModalWindow. I also played around with 'renderOnDomReadyJavascript', 'renderOnLoadJavascript' etc., but I guess it has to be embedded in the body-tag anyway... I just can't get it to work.

It's working if I embed the panel into a page and put that page into the ModalWindow instead of the panel, but I want to avoid that because it's not necessary and results in scrolling issues. Thanks for any hints!

EDIT: Quickstart-Example which shows the problem: [Download](http://d.pr/f/U9lo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is illustrated [in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471526/use-syntax-highlighter-on-ajax-loaded-content). Method highlight() must be used in place of all().

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that when you work with panels you don't have the used JavaScript function properly declared. In other words object SyntaxHighlighter is not defined in your example when you use the embedded directly into ModalWindow.
Check panel's page to see if it defines some JavaScript library used by tour panel.

Comment: Hi Andrea (again ;-) ), the required JavaScript and CSS references are defined by overriding renderHead(...). I tried that in the Panel itself, as well as in a Behavior I added to the Panel. When I check the source in the browser, all required JS and CSS files are there in the HEAD-tag. It's not working though, only when I put the Panel into its own page, but not in a ModalWindow That's why I'm confused.

Comment: Don't you get any JavaScript error in your browser? Are you using some kind of tool like FireBug that can detect these kind of silent errors?
I'm pretty sure your JavaScript is executed, I mean if you replace your code inside panel with a simple alert('') it should be executed, right?

Comment: You are correct, an alert('test') works. So the script in the body is in fact executed. However, the SyntaxHighlighter is not working/recognized, even though I appended the JS-references to the Header. Like I said, I even tried to override the renderHead(...) method of the ModalWindow with stuff like 'response.renderJavaScriptReference("/media/js/shCore.js")' etc. It's not working, but I do find the required references in the head of the parent page. I have no clue anymore :(

Comment: Oh and I forgot: no, there are no errors in the JavaScript console! At least not in the console of the browser, I can also try 3rd-party tools like Firebug of course.

Comment: At this point I would try to debug your JavaScrip code. Put a breakpoint at the beginning of the invoked function ( i.e. SyntaxHighlighter.all()) and walk through the code until you find why it doesn't execute as expected.

Comment: Hi Andrea, I don't really know where to start there because of the div-embedding when using a ModalWindow. I just asked the mailing-list and created a slick quickstart which shows exactly my problem with two links. I edited my question. First link using just a panel -> not working. Second link a page I want to avoid -> working.