# How to do Syntax highlighting on code coming from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, syntax-highlighting

I need help with Alex Gorbatchev's syntax highlighting. Actually I am saving some code snippet in JSON file and then making AJAX calls to render it in JSP inside some div via JQuery. But the syntax highlighting is not working. If I put text directly then it works, but the content in my webapp is loaded dynamically!
Look at the code from debugger below:

Firefox

[image: Firefox]

Chrome

[image: Chrome]

Comment: I don't think you can have syntax highlighting on string inside chrome dev tools, but what does it look like on the actual page?

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. Test your AJAX calls in a regular browser to see the data they're returning. Are you trying to figure out why there's the random `== %0 "` in your second snippet? Look at what the AJAX is actually returning

Comment: @DBS The code comes as a plain text when rendered through Jquery, however on putting static text, its highlighted even though has some style issues like alignment etc.

Comment: @mmcrae See firefox element too! I dont think thats issue anyways since static code is highlighted. AJAX call response is fine.

Comment: @mmcrae -  The `== %0` is added by the chrome tools, indicating that *that* element can be accessed as `%0` in the console.  It isn't part of the markup.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on the version of SyntaxHighlighter You are using.

If You are using the latest version (4), you probably would like to use an [API](https://github.com/syntaxhighlighter/syntaxhighlighter/wiki/API):

```
highlight(params = {}, element = null)
```

If it's oldest version (3), You could try to restart hilighter via [`all`](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/installation.html) method:

```
SyntaxHighlighter.all()
```

Comment: This is the version: syntaxhighlighter_3.0.83
And it has to be local. I am using second version as was told in installation guide.

Comment: SyntaxHighlighter.highlight() is doing it, thanks!!. But there is serious styling issue. Let me see that now, and update here.
Got this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471526/use-syntax-highlighter-on-ajax-loaded-content?rq=1 with your suggestion.